# No solution when solving hard margin SVM

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning

> **Problem**: We consider a classification problem with two classes having equal probability and their corresponding points in R2 as follows:
> \begin{align*}
> &\text{Class } y_1 = 1: x_1 = (1,1)^T\\
> &\text{Class } y_2 = -1: x_2 = (-1,-1)^T, x_3 = (1,0)^T, x_4 =(0,1)^T.
> \end{align*}
> Find the separating hyperplane given by SVM classifier.

**My attempt:** Consider the Lagragian function
$$L(w,b,\alpha) = \dfrac{1}{2}\Vert w\Vert^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{4}\alpha_i(1-y_i(\langle w,x_i\rangle+b)),\ \alpha_i \ge 0.$$

KKT conditions for the primal problem:
\begin{align*}
&1-y_i(\langle w,x_i\rangle+b \le 0, \forall i= \overline{1,4} \tag{1}\\
&\alpha_i \ge 0, \forall i = \overline{1,4}. \tag{2}\\
&\alpha_i(1-y_i(\langle w,x_i\rangle+b) = 0 \tag{3}\\
&\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial w}(w,b,\alpha) = w - \sum_{i=1}^{4}\alpha_i y_i x_i = 0 \tag{4}\\
&\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial b}(w,b,\alpha) = - \sum_{i=1}^{4}\alpha_i y_i = 0 \tag{5}
\end{align*}

Hence, the dual Lagrangian function is
$$g(\alpha) = \dfrac{-1}{2}\alpha^T H\alpha + \alpha^T\cdot 1,$$
where $H = [H_{ij}]_{i,j=\overline{1,4}}$, with $H_{ij} = y_iy_j\langle x_i,x_j\rangle$.
The dual problem now is
\begin{align*}
&\max_{\alpha} g(\alpha) \Leftrightarrow \min_{\alpha} \left\{\dfrac{1}{2}\alpha^T H \alpha - \alpha^T \cdot 1\right\}\\
\text{s.t }& \alpha_i \ge 0, \forall i = \overline{1,4}\\
&\sum_{i=1}^{4} \alpha_iy_i = 0.
\end{align*}

KKT conditions for the dual problem:
$$L_D(\alpha,\lambda) = \dfrac{1}{2}\alpha^T H \alpha - \alpha^T \cdot 1 + \lambda\sum_{i=1}^4 \alpha_i y_i$$
\begin{align*}
&\alpha_i \ge 0 \tag{6}\\
&\sum_{i=1}^4 \alpha_iy_i = 0 \tag{7}\\
&H\alpha -1 + \lambda y = 0 \tag{8}
\end{align*}
Combining (7) and (8), we have the linear systems of 5 equations and 5 variables. I expected that this system has a solution but it did not. So, I wonder why it happened because if the dual problem has no solution then the primal does. But by plotting these data points, we can easily see the separating hyperplane.